# Has WinSock Registered IO performance degraded since 2012?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, udp, winsock

I have recently written a UDP reception based on WinSock Registered IO (RIO) using the somewhat acceptable documentation MS provides for this API. The resulting performance is very disappointing: somewhat stable single socket performance of around 180k packets per second - around 260k packets per second when using multiple RSS queues (i.e. multiple sockets). The code has been profiled using Tracy and the results suggest that everything is in working order.

Up until now one might be tempted to think that I have just done a bad job at writing the code I gathered these numbers from. Therefore, I have searched online and found [blog posts from 2012](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/rio/) that suggest single socket performance to be at least 450k packets per second. I downloaded the code and ran it on may test setup (back to back 10 Gb/s connected machines) and got similar performance to mine.

And now it gets interesting: after writing an email to the blogger I got the code from, he tried it out on his machines and also came to the conclusion that "RIO performance is disappointing" and that basic blocking IO outperforms it (at least in this single socket setup). Unfortunately, he does not have the time for further investigation on why the code from 2012 results in worse performance on better hardware.

All tests were performed on Windows 10 Pro based machines and at least on my side with (presumably) appropriate NIC configuration and no SMT/HyperThreading. The system was not under any load while conducting the tests.

It is true that the question I initially asked, could be rephrased to: did the RIO API change such that code written in 2012 is now performing very badly? Or: how does a "modern" approach to using RIO look like? Or: should RIO be used at all in 2021?

Comment: Did you test it on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: No, I don't have access to such a setup. However, the blogger wanted to test it with the same setup from 2012 again (same hard- and software) but does not have time to get everything up and running atm. This is why I am asking here - maybe someone has an idea what happened over the years.

Comment: Is this such a bad question or why is nobody interested in getting to the bottom of this issue? I would at least expect someone to tell me that I (or the blog posts I have linked to) am doing something wrong or that RIO is just not what I think it is. Maybe my expectations are wrong and there is no such thing as single socket performance of >= 450k packets per second...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working (and fighting) also with UDP and RIO under Win10 and Win11. I'm not a big fan of changing thread and process priorities, but ...

I'm getting the best performance result by setting the Thread Prioirty (of the Dequeue thread) to `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL`.
(I assume this will increase the IO Priority of the UDP recption. I can not find a lot of docu to verify this: [perhaps here](https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7))

In addition I've adjusted the process priority class to `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`

Comment: I am also changing at least the dequeue thread priority like you have suggested. This indeed increases the stability of the whole setup. Do you have any hard numbers with respect to the potentially increased 'packet per second' performance? It is just sad that I still do not get close to Linux network performance after all this time...

Comment: I'm working with a gigabit Ethernet and ~4K Jumboframes. So i think it's not very similar to your setup.